# Android Studio: App keeps crashing on the device after being completely closed

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

This is a weird behavior i have observed recently.

My app works perfectly without any error on my test device(tablet), but after i  close the app and remove it from Recent Apps list, I get the message "Unfortunately MY APP has stopped".

Also, **this Crash message keeps repeating itself periodically**.

As there are no errors or warnings when i run the app, i am not able to find out the reason for it.

Any help on this topic would be a great.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a periodic thing like an alarm/broadcast receiver/service running?

Comment: You can look at the logcat console output for an error and see exactly where the error is occurring.

Comment: In my experience it's most likely `Performing stop of Activity that is not resumed.` Check out the [SO question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375920/android-performing-stop-of-activity-that-is-not-resumed) for some more information. Without LogCat output (which you can get while your app is still in the background), we don't know for sure.