# Android taking picture crash

Tags: android, camera

I am making an app that uses camera and I need the full photo in order to edit it. I followed this tutorial from Google developers ([Link](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/training/camera/photobasics.html)) and it is working on some devices, but not on Galaxy S4 5.0.1. I get force close of Camera application with this exception in LogCat:

```
Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sec.android.app.camera/...}
```

Here is my code (literally copy-pasted from Google):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 152;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    ImageView mImageView;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            setPic();
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void setPic() {
        mImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void button(View v) {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }
}
```

Android manifest has these 3 lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: I had this problem once. Resolved using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375920/android-performing-stop-of-activity-that-is-not-resumed. Hope this helps