# Error when launching app on device start

Tags: java, android, onresume

I am building an application that needs to start when my android device first boots up which works fine. I am parsing an XML file and based off the value I get from the XML file I start another Activity from my main activity but when I 
started trying to start an Activity from my MainActivity onCreate I started getting the following error.

```
01-03 12:06:41.170    7854-7854/com.example.asiahyd.gpsdemo E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.asiahyd.gpsdemo/com.example.asiahyd.gpsdemo.MyActivity}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.asiahyd.gpsdemo/com.example.asiahyd.gpsdemo.MyActivity}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

This is my MainActivity onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    check = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("startUp");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Automation";

    File f = new File(baseDir);
    int numOfFiles = f.listFiles().length;

    File[] temp = f.listFiles();

    try {
        parseData(temp[0]);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(check == true){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Result.class);
        i.putExtra("coldSelected", coldSelected);
        i.putExtra("warmSelected", warmSelected);
        i.putExtra("hotSelected", hotSelected);
        i.putExtra("onDeviceLogging", 0);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Then this is the activity I use to start my application on device bootup

```
public class Bootup extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Reboot completed! Starting your app!!!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("startUp", true);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

If anyone has any insight into why I might be getting this error I would really appreciate the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Performing stop of activity that is not resumed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375920/android-performing-stop-of-activity-that-is-not-resumed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar problem found here: [Similar Issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947675/android-4-4-2-java-lang-runtimeexception-performing-stop-of-activity-that-is). The solution seemed to be adding your Intent to either onResume() or onPostResume(). This is due to the app running on higher end phones.

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //XML parse and intent here
}
```

or:

```
public void onPostResume(){
    super.onPostResume();
    //XML parse and intent here
}
```

Also this was another viable answer:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
        case 1:
          //start activity with intent here

        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

And in onResume call this.

```
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 1000);
```

**Side note:** I'd also like to suggest creating an intent as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
```

I can provide a long winded answer as to why, but in short don't use getApplicationContext() unless you know why :)

Comment: hmm I still seem to get the error even when added to onResume and onPostResume

Comment: Did you try with the Handler? This delays the call a second, then tells the handler thread to start your activity. Kind of a poor solution, but does tell you that the problem is the call needs to be delayed. Also, what device are you running this on

Comment: no worries, accept the answer so that others with your problem will know that it works :)